# OpenAL Turn Off Soft Start

Tags: macos, audio, openal

I am using OpenAL and when I call alSourcePlay() my sound buffer starts "softly". I could not find a way to start with the AL_GAIN instead. Picture shows two records, first is how I want it (I have simulated it by feeding a stream buffer without stopping the play). Second record is what happening when call alSourcePlay() with the new buffer. Any ideas how to start without soft start?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Single channel sounds are treated by OpenAL as positional audio (in 3D space), so if you want your Mono sound file to play "globally", regardless of position, you can run this before starting playback:

```
alSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE, AL_TRUE);
```

This works very well.

Alternatively, you would have to set the position for both the listener and source to be the same, every frame, but that would be a waste of CPU cycles and could potentially result in the audio source "lagging" behind (being played from behind) if you're traveling at a high speed (e.g. inside a vehicle or plane) and your game loop updates the position too slowly because, for example, runs at a lower fps for a short amount of time.

Also, turning a Mono sound file into Stereo by duplicating the audio channel is a waste of memory and results in slightly longer loading times (because its processing the same data twice). Don't ever do that.

Comment: Thank you @Andrei, I will try that. My other problem is that "soft start" -- see image below. There is about a 0.011s linear "fade in" period when first time start to play the stream. That happens every time I start playing. I am writing a vintage computer emulator and generating the sound buffer by hand, but this fade in effect makes sound different than what you can hear on the real hardware. If I do not stop playing, it sounds the same (because there is no fade in effect). Any idea for that?

Answer (score 1):

I think finally I have found something. It turns out OpenAL does not use 3D spatialization when dealing with stereo buffers, so moving from Mono to Stereo gives a better results -- not exactly what I need, but definitely much closer to that. 3rd image is what I get with this workaround. As you can see there is still a "soft start" or fade in start, but much less attenuated and I can reach max level this way, while in Mono mode it always stayed at a lower amplitude.

[image]

Comment: Have you ever found a way to turn off this fade in / soft start?